# Excluding folder from Build operation in Visual Studio 2019 .NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have created ASP.Net web application and added Angular 11 application inside the web application as sub folder called "AngularApp". I have added below settings in ".csproj" to exclude "AngularApp" folder during ASP.Net web application build process. But I am getting build errors related with "node_modules" even after excluding the folder during build process. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="AngularApp\**" />
  <Content Remove="AngularApp\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="AngularApp\**" />
  <None Remove="AngularApp\**" />
  <Content Include="AngularApp\dist\prod\**\*" />
  <Content Update="AngularApp\dist\prod\**\*;appsettings.json;web.config">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Because this is a web application project (as opposed to a .NET SDK based project), files are excluded unless something includes them.  Your removals shouldn't be necessary unless something else is including them.  Is there another competing glob pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this in your csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- display folder in solution explorer -->
    <Content Include="AngularApp\**"/>    

    <!-- ignore the folder while building -->
    <Compile Include="AngularApp\**" Exclude="AngularApp\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```